# Using velocity HTML templates inside Eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse, velocity

I use velocity (vm) files in Eclipse which are mainly HTML with some velocity commands. I wonder how I can properly syntax highlight these files.

At the moment I am using HTML syntax highlighting which is ok, but all velocity commands appear as errors.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [contributed Velocity development tools](https://wiki.apache.org/velocity/VelocityEditors) page, Eclipse section. Some of them may be outdated.